# cross validation in pipeline python

Tags: python, pipeline, cross-validation

I have this pipeline:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
("fasttext", FastTextVectorTransformer()),
("umap",umap_skl(n_components=8)),
("classifier", HistGradientBoostingClassifier())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f'Fbeta_score:{fbeta_score(y[test_index], pipe.predict(X[test_index]), average=None, beta=1.4)}')
print(f'Accuracy:{accuracy_score(y[test_index], pipe.predict(X[test_index]))}')
print(f'Precission:{precision_score(y_test, pipe.predict(X[test_index]))}')
print(f'Recall:{recall_score(y_test, pipe.predict(X_test))}')    
print(f'Roc_AUC:{roc_auc_score(y_test, pipe.predict(X_test))}')
```

And I need to report the scores use coss Validation.
How can I add cross validation to the pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried : `cross_val_score()` function from the `sklearn.model_selection` module ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but the problem I have is that I need to make the partitions for test and train since the data is different. I need another way to do it.